# I want to add Modernizr to an angular (version 7) app, how can i do that?

Tags: angular7, modernizr

How can i **add modernizr** to my application? 
I try to install with **mpm**
Import * as modernizr from 'modernizer';
but i can't use it.

Answer (score 1):

I added it in index.html as script and it works. I didn't find better way to do this...